# How do I code a proxy for the .pop method without actually using the .pop method?

Tags: python

I am attempting (well I have solved it, just not the "right" way) to solve the following problem:

A Stack is a type of list where instead of accessing
any item in the list at any time, you can only add
or remove items from the top of the Stack.

Adding a new item to the stack is called "pushing"
the item onto the stack. Removing the top item on
the stack is called "popping" the item off the stack.
When an item is "popped" off the stack, it is removed
from the list altogether.
Write a class called Stack. Stack should have the
following methods:

An **init** method that initializes the empty list
that is the stack's contents.

A stack_push() method that takes one parameter (in
addition to self): an item to push onto the top
of the stack.

A stack_pop() method that returns the current top
item on the stack and removes it from the underlying
list. If the list is already empty, this returns
None.

For example, the following code would print the
numbers 3, 2, and 1 (in that order). Note that this
is the opposite order of how they are pushed: the
pop method will always return the elements in the
reverse order that they were added in.

```
new_stack = Stack()
new_stack.stack_push(1)
new_stack.stack_push(2)
new_stack.stack_push(3)
print(new_stack.stack_pop())
print(new_stack.stack_pop())
print(new_stack.stack_pop())
```

Add your class here!

Here is what I came up with:

```
class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.a_list =[]
   
     def stack_push(self,num):
         self.a_list.append(num)
        
     def stack_pop(self):
         return self.a_list.pop()
```

This works, but I am not allowed to use the .pop method in the last line. Any thoughts? Here is the code that test my class:

The following lines of code will test your class.
If it works correctly, it will print 3, 2, and 1
in that order, each on their own line.

```
new_stack = Stack()
new_stack.stack_push(1)
new_stack.stack_push(2)
new_stack.stack_push(3)
print(new_stack.stack_pop())
print(new_stack.stack_pop())
print(new_stack.stack_pop())
```

My code DOES print 3,2,1 in this order, each integer on a separate line. Again though, I am not supposed to use .pop which I didn't realize until after I solved this. Plus, I am basically a beginner and was introduced to the .pop method in this question.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to implement a stack would be to emulate how the actual CPU stack works on your computer:

- allocate a very long list for the stack
- have an integer variable which contains the last used position in the stack, let's call it `SP`.
- `push` increases `SP` and puts the value in `stack[SP]`
- `pop` returns `stack[SP]` and decreases `SP`

Note that you also need to handle stack under- and overflows (which your original code is missing either).

Answer (score -1):

The last element appended to the list can be retrieved with

```py
last_el = self.a_list[-1]
```

but then you still need to remove it from the list to 'pop' it out,
so you could then do

```
self.a_list = self.a_list[:-1]
```

all together you get:

```
def stack_pop(self):
  last_el = self.a_list[-1]
  self.a_list = self.a_list[:-1]
  return last_el
```

but this is probably less efficient than using .pop() anyway.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have tried this as well and it is just returning my list 3 times.